# Score in Unity game only increases by 1 and then stops

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I am trying to create a score in unity where if you collect coins (in my case shells) the score goes up by 1 each time, however, the score increases by 1 and then stops increasing and I am not sure why.

Script attached to coin (shell):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;

public class ShellController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float coin = 0; // is it because every time player collides with shell, this resets the score back to zero? if so, how do I only set it to zero once, in the beggining? 
    public TextMeshProUGUI textCoins;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if(collision.tag == "Player")
        {
            SoundManagerScript.PlaySound("winCoin");
            coin ++;
            textCoins.text = coin.ToString();
            Destroy(gameObject);
            
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code attached to the label (text) which displays the score:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ScoreTextScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    Text text;
    public static int coinAmount;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        text = GetComponent<Text>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        text.text = coinAmount.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: `ShellController` has a score that starts at 0. When the player collides with it it increases that score value to 1 and then destroys itself. It will never be larger than 1 because it always starts at 0 and only increases once. You might want to store the coin amount on an object that has a longer lifetime.

Answer (score 2):

Because `ShellController` will be destroyed which player collision by `OnTriggerEnter2D` event, but `ShellController` initials `coin` as 0 for each shell game object, so that why you might always get `1` instead of increase number.

```
private float coin = 0;

coin ++;
textCoins.text = coin.ToString();
```

We can try to increase `coinAmount` field from `ScoreTextScript` game Object from each `ShellController` game object and keep the value in `ScoreTextScript` game object.

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if(collision.tag == "Player")
    {
        SoundManagerScript.PlaySound("winCoin");        
        textCoins.coinAmount++;
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: I changed it to `textCoins.coinAmount++;` however I get an error message in visual studio saying:  'TextMeshProUGUI' does not contain a definition for 'coinAmount' and no accessible extension method 'coinAmount' accepting a first argument of type 'TextMeshProUGUI' could be found.

Comment: I provide a sample code from your logic I would pass `ScoreTextScript` game object to increase the value

Comment: I changed it to `ScoreTextScript.coinAmount++;` but now the score does not increase at all.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple collision method for UNIITY to collect gold coins

```
   void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
  {

    if (col.gameObject.tag == "Player")//If the collision object is the player
    {
     money++;//money plus one
     Destroy(this.gameObject);//Destroy gold coins
    }
}
```

Create a gold coin model and paste the above code in its C# code to collect gold coins. If you need to modify the display information of money on the existing UI

```
     GameObject ifCollect = GameObject.Find("/Canvas/TextTwo");//" "Where is your UI
     ifCollect.GetComponent<Text>().text = money.ToString();//Change money
```